# Docker command not available on Windows 7

Tags: linux, windows-7, docker, boot2docker

So I am using Docker with `boot2docker` for quite some time on Windows, and everything works ok. Recently, it started bothering me that in order to run docker commands, I have to start `Boot2Docker` terminal, and type there `boot2docker ssh`, and from virtual machine run docker commands. What I find strange is that after starting Boot2Docker terminal(without ssh-ing into vm), this is the output:

```
initializing...
Virtual machine boot2docker-vm already exists

starting...
Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start...
.o
Started.
Writing C:\Users\user\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\ca.pem
Writing C:\Users\user\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\cert.pem
Writing C:\Users\user\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\key.pem

To connect the Docker client to the Docker daemon, please set:
    export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376
    export DOCKER_CERT_PATH='C:\Users\user\.boot2docker\certs\boot2do                      cker-vm'
    export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1


IP address of docker VM:
192.168.59.103

setting environment variables ...
Writing C:\Users\user\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\ca.pem
Writing C:\Users\user\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\cert.pem
Writing C:\Users\user\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\key.pem
    export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376
    export DOCKER_CERT_PATH='C:\\Users\\user\\.boot2docker\\certs\\bo                      ot2docker-vm'
    export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1

You can now use `docker` directly, or `boot2docker ssh` to log into the VM.
```

After that, I can run `boo2docker.exe ssh`, and from vm docker command. However without ssh-ing:

```
$ docker.exe
bash: docker.exe: command not found
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Same issue here - docker toolbox install doesn't add docker to the path.

Just manually add the `docker.exe` to your path - mine was installed to program files docker toolbox.

```
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why `docker.exe`? try only `docker`. Or rather, try `docker version`. If this works, you can use all the docker commands smoothly.

Secondly, Boot2Docker has been deprecated recently. Its much more simple now. : https://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/

Comment: docker.exe or docker, same thing..command not found. Btw. I also tried Docker Toolbox few days ago, it was a nightmare. Every time I started it, new network adapter was created for some reason and I was notified about IP conflict in the network. I made it to work, but there was also other issues and at that moment I got rid of it. Boot2Docker works really great for me.

Comment: Dont know about the network related stuff with docker on windows..have mostly used in linux dstributions.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the installation had created a PATH *user* variable, as opposed to adding the docker.exe directory to the PATH *system* variable. I fixed the path manually and it worked.

Comment: Slightly different. In my case, the installer did create a PATH variable. However, the path variable was a user variable, not a system variable. As such, it was useless for the docker toolbox terminal.